# How to resolve a javascript problem, using google chome dev tools? What is the usual process to solve this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm designing a test page with javascript and i have the following issue

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollToFixed is not a function
    at ________(scripts.js:16)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:838)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.9.1.js:103)
```

How to resolve this and relative problems, using google chrome dev tools? What is the usual process a user goes through to fix a javascript problem? When i have a javascript and the problem is subject to a . or ; or a missing bracket, the solution is easy to find it. But how to, when you have a message like above about the javascript problem?

Comment: So `scrollToFixed` is not added. Look for the script include

Comment: What library did you include (or forget to include) that implements a scollToFixed function?

Comment: Ask yourself why you think `scrollToFixed` **should** be a function, and then trance through the code / build minimal test cases to work out why it isn't.

Comment: Each bracket on each line lists the filename and line number of the code which raised the error message. For instance, `scripts.js` in line `16` is the function in which you have a call to `scrollToFixed`, and the lines show the ancestor function calls, the functions that were called in succession till you get the error on `scripts.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a breakpoint at line 16 of scripts.js. That gives you the ability to see what the variables are at that point in the execution of the program.

Reload the page and when the debugger pauses there, then in the console window, type $(...) - I'm assuming you have something like "button" in place of "..." and see if it even exists. You can also hover over the $(...) part in the source code on the breakpointed line and it will show a popup with its value. You can see what the thing is and perhaps it's not what you thought it was and that's why the function isn't present. Maybe you were wrong about that function being on the type of thing you've retrieved with $().  At any rate, you'll be further along if you can inspect the values in place.